# bibentry macro with ConTeXt

Tags: bibtex, context

I am trying to get the `\bibentry` (bibtex) or `\fullcite` behavior with ConTeXt. My MnWE is:

```
\setupbibtex[database={library},sort=author]
\setuppublications[alternative=apa]

\starttext
blablabla\cite{Bohr:1923tl}

\section{References}
\placepublications[criterium=all]

\stoptext
```

with the bib-file:

```
@article{Bohr:1923tl,
author = {Bohr, N},
title = {{The structure of the atom}},
journal = {Nature},
year = {1923},
volume = {112},
pages = {29--44}
}
```

My output is:

[image: output]

but I would like to have to full line similar to the one in references (I am using mkiv). Something such as `\placepublications[key=Bohr:1923tl]`.

To give some context ;), here is the first page of a book. Note how the reference is put in the margin, so I was thinking about `\def\sidecite#1{\inouter{\fullcite{#1}}}`, but there is no `\fullcite`? (sorry, German)

[image: example page]

Comment: You want the full citation in text **every time** you cite the reference?

Comment: Yes, every time. I edited the question to point out, what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
blablabla\cite[data][Bohr:1923tl]
```

Comment: This does not work for me. The output is very strange: `blablabla ()..., ()` and then a frame with the text `external figure no name`.

Comment: @Andy: my context reports: `ConTeXt  ver: 2012.04.26 22:27 MKIV`. If yours is much older, then you should probably upgrade.

Comment: I updated and then realized that a clicked `ConTeXt` instead of `ConTeXt (LuaTeX)` in TeXShop. So everything works fine for me in mkiv, but the newest mkii still has the error. It doesn't matter to me, but maybe it is supposed to work in mkii as well.