# citation macro with ConTeXt

Tags: bibliographies, context

Consider the following example (background in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55278/bibentry-macro-with-context)).

```
\setupbibtex[database={library},sort=author]
\setuppublications[alternative=apa]

%\define[1]\reference{\cite[data][#1]}

\starttext
\cite[data][Bohr:1923tl]
%\reference{Bohr:1923tl}

\section{References}
\placepublications[criterium=all]

\stoptext
```

after running it through Mk-IV is shows the expected behavior:

[image: without_define]

Simply defining a macros by uncommenting `define` – without even using it – breaks it. (`def` does not help either).

[image]

How to define citation macros?

Comment: That’s because `\reference` is an [internal Context macro](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/reference) which is used to, well, place references (for internal links). Every entry in the bibliography happens to have such a reference, but as you changed the macro definition, breakage ensues as expected ... call it `\bibref` and things should work.

Comment: Please make this an answer, so I can accept it and less people see what I have done...

Comment: Here you go. Also it would be more precise to remove the tag `[bibtex]` from this question as MkIV does not rely on Bibtex even though it takes `.bib` files as input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To elaborate a bit on my comment: `\reference` is the Context user interface [macro](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/reference) to the pdf hyperlink facility (for the curious: it is defined among similar commands in [*strc-ref.mkvi*](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/strc-ref.mkvi)). It is used internally as well, for instance in the macro `\thebibtexpublicationlistelement`, which typesets a single entry of the bibliography list (cf. [bibl-bib.mkiv](http://repo.or.cz/w/context.git/blob/refs/heads/origin:/tex/context/base/bibl-bib.mkiv)).

For this reason, redefining `\reference` is a Bad Idea™: It will definitely break automatically generated references, the corrupted bibliography being collateral damage. If you use `\define`, Context will kindly give you a hint in the log file:

```
system          > command \reference is already defined
```

Choose a harmless macro identifier instead: *Capitalization* for instance will ensure that a macro never conflicts with any of the internals. Thus, `\Reference` is the preferable choice.